# production.rb wasn't pushed to heroku

Tags: railstutorial.org

Ok, I've just finished chapter 10, and was hoping to see the email sent from the production to my gmail account when I tested the "forgot password" logic.

It didn't work.  I know why, but I'm not sure how the two versions of production.rb got out of sync.

Now I'm on the (master) branch for sample_app, and I'm getting these messages when I try to push...

```
abundantmind:~/workspace/sample_app (master) $ git push
Everything up-to-date
abundantmind:~/workspace/sample_app (master) $ git push heroku
Everything up-to-date
abundantmind:~/workspace/sample_app (master) $
```

Which confuses me, because the relevant lines in the production.rb file look like this...

```
# Ignore bad email addresses and do not raise email delivery errors.
# Set this to true and configure the email server for immediate delivery to raise delivery errors.
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
# host = '<your heroku app>.herokuapp.com'
host = 'serene-dusk-31281.herokuapp.com'
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: host }
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
```

And on heroku, the same section of production.rb looks like this...

```
# Ignore bad email addresses and do not raise email delivery errors.
# Set this to true and configure the email server for immediate delivery to raise delivery errors.
# config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

# Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
```

Now my questions...

1)  Why does git tell me everything's in sync when it clearly isn't?

(Actually, I'm pretty sure git doesn't lie, so I accept that the issue is between the keyboard and the chair)

and

2)  What's the easiest way to push just the production.rb up to heroku (and bitbucket) so that I can move forward with Chapter 12?

Answer (score 0):

Have you merged your branch to master?
if not run this

`$ git merge account-activation-password-reset`

First do the new commit on push all files on github or bitbucket whichever you are using

```
$ git push origin master
```

then try to deploy your application again on heroku and migrate it again.

```
$ git push heroku
$ heroku run rake db:migrate
```